# Intermittent database connection issue but only with certain sites

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

I have a very freaky issue I'm struggling to find a solution to.

I have a Windows 2012 web server and a separate Windows 2012 server running SQL Server 2012.  Only recently installed.

The servers have 2 network cards - one public the other a direct connection between the two.

I have a number of database driven websites on the web server.  All connecting to the same database and in many case all using an identical connection string.

My code is ASP and in all cases using this connection string:

```
MyDBConn_STRING = "Provider=sqloledb;
Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Data Source=169.254.210.158;
Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;
User ID=database_user;
password=mypassword"
```

This all works fine.  Indeed had been running and working fine for a few days.

When suddenly I start seeing these errors in the logs:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]Specified SQL server not
>   found.. .

Re-starting the server fixes the problem but obviously involves downtime and so hardly a viable solution.

What is odd is that although all websites are using the same connection string - its just one website that suffered the issue - the others continued to connect fine.

And the website that does have issues has no problems server pages - so the public connection appears fine - but is suddenly unable to connect to the database server via TCP IP.

All the sites are set up with very similar configurations - largely the default.

Each has its own application pool.

So far its not happening often but the server has only been live 2 days - so its once in 2 days so far.

I've searched the Internet for solutions but its not a common issue!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like a networking/routing issue. Is the IP of the problem website on a different network from the others?

Comment: Also check the route back from the db to the webserver. If the request comes from its public IP the return message may go another route and be lost

Comment: No all sites on the same web server connecting back to the same database server.

Comment: Whats freaky is why all sites except one work.  All one same dedicated server.  Its like that particular site/app pool has lost connectivity for just the local network card.   And when it loses it - it loses it until its re-started when suddenly it works again and so far working for 3 hours

Comment: Check the bindings on the websites

Comment: If it happened once it's hard to say whether it has something todo with that single site or whether you just run out of connections on database server (sp_who2 in SSMS with 200 results is normal) or ports (DOS Command netstat -nbt with like 200 results is normal). From experience I have seen that these intermittence quite often come from non closed connections. A good indication on the moment supreme is for instance "netstat -nbt".

Comment: After more time and research the issue appears that a single worker process loses the ability to connect to the database.  While at the same time all the other worker processes in the application pool continue to work fine.   Re-cycling the application pool is enough to get things working again but not an ideal solution.

Comment: Finally got close to solving the issue.  Turned out to be failure to close a recordset object rather than just setting it to nothing